# create a random array and check if the user input is inside it

Tags: c, arrays

I am a beginner in C and I have to write a program that creates an array with random numbers between 0-100(user chooses the size 50/100/150). Then user will enter an input and the program will check if it exists in the array. I wrote something like this but it crashes when ran.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

    void populateArray(int *arr, int size)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        arr[i] = rand() % 100 + 1;
    }
}
    int check (int *arr, int size, int m)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]); i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] == m)
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
int main()
{

    int difficulty;
    int m;
    int size;
    int result;
    int arr[size];
    printf("Press 0 for beginner\nPress 1 for intermediate\nPress 2 for advanced");
    printf("Enter the difficulty level of the game:");
    scanf("%d", &difficulty);
    if (difficulty == 0)
    {
        size = 150;
        populateArray(arr, size);
    }
    if (difficulty == 1)
    {
        size = 100;
        populateArray(arr, size);

    }
    if (difficulty == 2)
    {
        int size = 50;
        populateArray(*arr, size);
    }
    printf("Enter your guess (between 0 and 100): ");
    scanf ("%d", &m);
     check (arr, size, m);
     result = check;
    if (result == 1)
        {
        printf("Congrats! You win!");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Gameover!");
        }
}
```

Comment: Well what is the "crash" message and at what line?

Comment: `int arr[size];` - I'm surprised that this compiles. `size` has not been set. Do you have warnings enabled?

Comment: What is this?  "check (arr, size, m);      result = check;" that is wrong.  You mean, "result = check (arr, size, m);"?  This should generate at least a warning when you compile.  Make sure you have warnings enabled. I would recommend  reading some C tutorials.

Comment: I am using codeblocks. Code compiles and exe opens but than it stops working.

Comment: in `int check (int *arr, int size, int m)`, `sizeof(arr)` is the size of a pointer, not the size of an array.

Answer (score 1):

```
check (arr, size, m);
result = check;
```

I think you mean as below:

```
result = check (arr, size, m);
```

Because size of `arr` change for each option of `fifficulty`, so you should use pointer `int * arr` instead of `int arr[size]`. Because, in your code `size` is not initialized, so you can not declare `int arr[size]`.

When you declare: `int *arr` you have to allocate for `arr` each `difficulty` option:

```
if (difficulty == 0)
    {
        size = 150;
        arr = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
        if(!arr) {
            // handle error
            return -1;
        }
        populateArray(arr, size);
    }
    if (difficulty == 1)
    {
        size = 100;
        arr = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
        if(!arr) {
            // handle error
            return -1;
        }
        populateArray(arr, size);

    }
    if (difficulty == 2)
    {
        int size = 50;
        arr = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
        if(!arr) {
            // handle error
            return -1;
        }
        populateArray(arr, size);
    }
```

Do not forget free `arr` at the end of main function:

```
free(arr);
```

OT, int `populateArray` funtion, do not need to declare the variable `int i;` (out of for loop). Or if you declare `int i;` then, do not need to declare `i` in for loop.
Thank to @chux - Reinstate Monica, i updated one failure in your code:

```
i < sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])
```

Using `size` in the argument of function instead.

Comment: Aside: A weakness to code like `arr = malloc(size * sizeof(int));` is that in review, the reviewer is obliged to seek the definition of `arr` to see if the matching type was used.  `arr = malloc(size * sizeof *arr);` is simpler to review, maintain and write correctly in the first place.

Comment: In the function check, do not need to use `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])` (it's not exact as you said in the comment) even if it was exact, the `size` in argument should be used in this function. So there is not problem with the malloc function

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't modify an array's size in runtime when allocated in the stack (via your `populateArray` function);  to do that you should use dynamically allocated arrays in the heap, e.g. use malloc(). The reason why the program compiles, and then even runs should be that C does not proof array boundaries at compile time or run time. Then at run time, when you try to assign values to your array with `'arr[i] = rand() % 100 + 1;'` your code accesses whatever memory it encounters (because the array size was not fixed so the array does not know what memory belongs to it) which leads to crash or unpredictable behavior.